# Case statement with truth values

Tags: ruby, typeerror

Two similar scripts are showing very strange behaviours here.

A) The code below is throwing a `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)`:

```
    score = 0
    ammount = 4

    score += case ammount
      when ammount >= 3; 10
      when ammount < 3; 1
    end

    puts score
```

B) And this other one is putting `1` into the console log.

```
    score = 0
    ammount = 4

    score += case ammount
      when ammount >= 3; 10
      else 1
    end

    puts score
```

I would expect both scripts to output `10` onto the console. Am I wrong? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When given an argument, the case statement checks for object equality (same as calling `===`), which can be used with single values or over ranges. In your case, you're not really checking for equality, but it can be written like this:

```
score += case
         when amount >= 3 then 10
         when amount < 3 then 1
         end
```

However, this is pretty verbose for what you're trying to do (an either/or condition). It's simpler to use a plain `if...else` or a ternary statement:

```
score += amount >= 3 ? 10 : 1
```

Comment: Oh, so its all about the argument! Thanks for fast answering.

PS.: By the way, this example was simplified so as to start the conversation, the real one is bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two types of case statement:

1. ```
   case variable
   when range/expression then ...
   else statement
   end
   ```
2. ```
   case
   when case1 then ...
   else ...
   end
   ```

**Question:**

Why your code does not work?

**Answer:**

When you specify a variable in `case`, an implicit `===` operation will be applied to each `when` test. In your case, `amount` is 4, and it is greater than 3, then amount>=3 is `true`, so the first when will test if `amount === true`. Apparently it is not, so it will go to next when, next one is `false` and it is not false either so the case statement will return `nil`, then you get an error saying `nil class cannot be coerced`.

The same for your second condition.

**Right solution** is to use one of the above:

either:

```
score = 0
ammount = 4

score += case
  when ammount >= 3; 10
  when ammount < 3; 1
end
```

or:

```
score = 0
ammount = 4

score += case ammount
  when 3..(1.0/0.0); 10
  when -(1.0/0.0)...3; 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using 'then' instead of ';' inside the case and not declare the ammount variable for the case, just use the clauses you have there.
Much easier to use the ternary operation to have the outcome you want:

```
score += ammount >= 3 ? 10 : 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what @ZachKemp said.

Comment: Sure, but in the case I had other options to the score variable. My examples were a lot simplified.

Comment: @MarkThomas saw it after submission... must have submitted around the same time..